# Looking for an iPad drawing app where you can do duplication

Tags: software-recommendation, sketching, ipad

Looking for an iPad drawing app where you can make a simple doodle, duplicate it within the same canvas say 5 times, and make alternations to each copy of the doodle. Does anyone know an app that makes such a simple workflow possible?

I have so far tried without success in the following apps: Notability, Penultimate, Pencil, Apple Notes, Goodnotes, and Paper.

Comment: If you have an Adobe CC subscription, Adobe Illustrator Draw might work for you. I haven't used the app in a long time so I am not 100% sure on this but I think you can duplicate layers and documents.

Comment: @AndrewH Unless a question is not on topic for us we don't generally migrate. This question in my opinion is in scope for our community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the more "obscure" drawing apps offer this sort of feature. These do, and in personal order of preference // with commentary:

**ibisPaint** // Funky, dated UI hiding VERY good performance and features. Good use of pressure in Pencil, too.

**MediBang Paint** // Busy UI, but ENORMOUS feature list. Incredible Power, like a desktop app on an iPad.

**Concepts** // Odd UI, but highly performant, and vector scaling of lines, plus excellent manipulation of selections, and duplicates

**Sketchbook (Pro)** // Has a dated UI for iOS, was one of the earlier drawing apps, but does have some of the best pens/pencils, still.

**Procreate** // Most famous painting app on iOS by a MILE!... but you will have to duplicate layers to get the ability you want, not select objects and copy/paste style duplication.

**Pixelmator** // same as above, you'll need to duplicate layers